# Fade effect doesn't apply on first hover

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a fade and slide effect, it actually work fine but there is still a problem on first hover, the fade effect doesn't apply, does someone know what's wrong ?

https://jsfiddle.net/y5zndn89/64/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".example").hide();
  $('.show').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.example').stop(true, false).animate({
      height: 'show'
    }, 200);
    $(this).siblings('.example').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 500
    });
  })
  $('.show').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.example').stop(true, false).animate({
      height: 'hide'
    }, 200);
    $(this).siblings('.example').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 200
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.example {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your hep.

Comment: i dont know where is your problem , because your fiddle is works fine on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve your issue by adding `opacity: 0;` to your css. Initially the opacity is already defined by default. The initial hover does not adjust that value since it's already the same. By setting it to 0, animation takes effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".example").hide();
    $('.show').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.example').stop(true, false).animate({
        height: 'show'
      }, 200);
      $(this).siblings('.example').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
      });
    })
    $('.show').mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.example').stop(true, false).animate({
        height: 'hide'
      }, 200);
      $(this).siblings('.example').animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 200
      });
    })
  });
```

```css
.example {
   background-color: blue;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">Div Text</div>
 <div>
  <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="example"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="example"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplyfy your code by using `fadeIn()` since you use jquery

here a example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".example").hide();
    $('.show').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).next().fadeIn(500)
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle(500)
    })
});
```

```css
.example {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
    <div class="example"></div>

</div>
<div>


    <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
    <div class="example"></div>
</div>
<div>

    <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
    <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set an opacity for the `.example` element, therefore the animation fades from 1 (which is default) to 1 (as specified in your mouseenter script).
On mouseleave the opacity is set to 0, so the second time you hover over `.show` the animation operates like it should, fading from 0 to 1.

To fix this, just add `opacity: 0;` to your css to set the initial opacity to 0.

```
.example {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y5zndn89/65/